# CSS/JavaScript highlight text by changing color when text is changed

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JavaScript that updates a `<p>` html every couple of seconds based on the return value from an ajax call. I'd like to add a nice effect on the `<p>` so that whenever the html inside `<p>` changes, the background of the `<p>` changes to some other color for a second and then change back.

It is similar to how Yahoo Finance page shows the current price of a stock. - eg https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA?p=BABA

How would I achieve something like this, preferably using CSS?

So far, I've tried the following.

```
<script>
setInterval(function () {
               $("#bid").html(Math.random()).addClass('textColor').delay(1000).removeClass('textColor');
}, 1000);
</script>
```

And CSS

```
<style>
        .textColor {
            background-color: coral;
        }

    </style>
```

And HTML

```
<p id="bid"></p>
```

It looks like the effect is too fast, so the color change is not even visible.

https://jsfiddle.net/yn5gq1wd/1/

### Update:

Here is the latest jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yn5gq1wd/19/

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Please [do make an attempt to solve your own problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've tried few that I got from few google searches. Nothing is the way that I wanted. Will update the question with few examples that I tried in a few.

Comment: Edited question and added jsfilddle attempt that I've made

Comment: I think this question has been edited correctly, the close votes should be retracted. Good work @getvivekv I don't normally see such a recovery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a css class that has the background color you want to change it to.

When the html in the paragraph changes, add the css class to the paragraph and then use the setTimeout() method to remove the class after a set time (in milliseconds).

Here is an example of using setTimeout to add and remove the class on clicking the paragraph. You just need to replace the click event with some other event to fire the code.

```
<script>
    $("#bid").click(function() {
        $("#bid").addClass('textColor');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#bid").removeClass('textColor');
        }, 1000);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I think I've attempted to do this using jQuery delay(). Didn't work as expected

Comment: Thanks, looks like this did the trick - https://jsfiddle.net/yn5gq1wd/23/

Answer (score 1):

Use MutationObserver:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('spy-on-me');
setInterval(function () { // This is just to show how it works
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + element.innerHTML;
}, 3000);

const observer = new MutationObserver( function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    if (mutation.type = 'childList') {
      element.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
      setTimeout(function () {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      }, 200);
    }
  });
});

const config = { childList: true };

observer.observe(element, config);
```

```html
<p id="spy-on-me">
  some text
<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior in 3 steps:

**1. create one css animation keyframe**

```
@keyframes color-key-frame {
  from {color: black;}
  to {color: red;}
}
```

**2. create one css class that is playing the animation ones**

```
.color-animation {
  animation-name: color-key-frame ;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

**3. add the 'color-animation' class to the desired HTML node when your ajax call is finished**

```
   //inside your ajax callBack
    var node = document.getElementById('idOfyourNode');

    //remove prev adjusted class first
    if(node.classList.contains('color-animation')){
      node.classList.remove('color-animation');
    }
    //hack to skip one tick
    setTimout(setTimeout(function(){
      node.classList.add('color-animation');
    },0);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yn5gq1wd/3/  This is closer to what I need. Only thing is that it doesn't work after the first round

Comment: Thanks for your help. There were a typo and a missing bracket. I've added it, here is the latest fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/yn5gq1wd/19/  Its almost working as I expected, I see at once instant it is not changing the color